# Как получить личный id пользователя в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как сделать так, чтобы мне в личные сообщения после ввода команды /start приходил айди пользователя. Почитал форум, ничего не нашел/что-то упустил. Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI.

Comment: Можно обратиться просто к существующему боту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться командой `message.from_user.id`:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(mes): #mes - message
  id = mes.from_user.id #записываем в переменную id данные.
```